# Laravel find() does not get data from the DB

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-5.8

I have a resource Controller with this `index` method like this:

```
public function index()
{
        $args = [];
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(35, 12, 'book'));
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(37, 12, 'kit'));
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(38, 12, 'game'));

        $args['menu_links'] = [
            'books'     => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(25)->slug),
            'videos'    => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(24)->slug),
            'kits'      => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(23)->slug),
            'games'     => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(22)->slug),
        ];
    
        return view('frontend.shop.products.index', $args);
}
```

But it returns this error:

**Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object**

And when I `dd(Category::find(25), Category::find(24), Category::find(23), Category::find(22));` I get *NULL* results.

Meaning that it can not find data with specified ids.

However there are 25 records stored at the `categories` table:

[image]

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Here is `Category.php` Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use Sluggable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'cat_name'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function path()
    {
        return "/products/categories/$this->slug";
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'cat_parent_id', 'cat_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'cat_id', 'cat_parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_products', 'ctp_cat_id', 'ctp_prd_id');
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(News::class, 'category_news', 'ctn_cat_id', 'ctn_nws_id');
    }

    public function galleries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class, 'category_galleries', 'ctg_cat_id', 'ctg_gly_id');
    }

    public function uploaded()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UploadedFile::class, 'upf_object_id', 'cat_id')->where('upf_object_type_id', '=', '107');
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category', 'act_cat_id', 'act_art_id');
    }

    public function olympiadExam()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OlympiadExam::class, 'olympiads_exams_categories', 'oec_ole_id', 'oec_cat_id');
    }

    public function olympiadExamQuestion()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OlympiadExamQuestion::class, 'olympiads_exams_questions_categories', 'oes_cat_id', 'oes_oeq_id')->orderBy('oeq_number', 'asc');
    }

    public function attr_attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryAttribute::class, 'category_id', 'cat_id');
    } //

    public function attr_product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'prd_cat_att_id', 'cat_id');
    } //

    public function couponRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(couponRelation::class, 'object_id', 'cat_id')->where('object_type', 'product_category');
    }

    public function magazines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Magazine::class, 'category_magazine', 'category_id', 'magazine_id');
    }

}
```

And when I do: `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25), Category::where('cat_id', 24), Category::where('cat_id', 23), Category::where('cat_id', 22));` I get this as result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more debug information, that includes the actual queries being run? Running `Category::where('cat_id', 25)->dd()` can help.

Comment: @erikgaal "select * from `categories` where `cat_id` = ? and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null"
array:1 [▼
  0 => 25
]

Comment: Does `Category` have the same behavior with `php artisan tinker`? `$cat = Category::find(10);` shows the expected output? I fail to detect an obvious error.. maybe the model name `Category` is ambiguous?

Comment: `Category::where('cat_id', 25)` is just the Eloquent query. You should call `Category::where('cat_id', 25)->first()` to make a comparison with `->find(25)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `SoftDeletes` so soft deleted models will automatically be excluded from query results. In your case, look like `Category` with id 22, 23, 24, 25 are soft deleted. To get it, you need to use `withTrashed()` as mentioned in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models). For example:

```
Category::withTrashed()->find(22)->slug
```

Comment: But Category::where works and they should not return trashed records

Comment: @imaginabit OP just called `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25))`, not `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25)->first())` so it's not actually return the result.

Answer (score 0):

per an answer above: if you are using soft deletes you need to add
`Category::withTrashed()`

However, you can wrap the command in an optional() helper function.

```
optional(Category::find(22))->slug

// if you are using soft delete
optional( Category::withTrashed()->find(22) )->slug
```

this will return null if 22 does not exist instead of throwing an exception error.